# Unreadable content of 'pathname' parameter in 'mkdir()' system call after inline hooking

Tags: c, linux-kernel, hook, system-calls

I'm trying inline hooking system calls. The hook function is like this:

```
asmlinkage long hooked_mkdir(const char __user *pathname, umode_t mode) {
        static char *msg = "hooked sys_mkdir(), mkdir name: ";
        printk("%s%s", msg, pathname);

        //print hex content to check bug.
        int i;
        for (i = 0; pathname[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            printk("\\x%x", pathname[i]);
        }

        return old_mkdir(pathname, mode);
}
```

Now I `mkdir` 3 directories named *111*, *222* and *333*. The syscalls were made successfully. However, the `pathname` is unreadable:

```
[ 4856.148778] hooked sys_mkdir(), mkdir name: `\xd0\xf1
                                                        \xfe
[ 4856.148779] \x60
[ 4856.148780] \xffffffd0
[ 4856.148780] \xfffffff1
[ 4856.148780] \xc
[ 4856.148781] \xfffffffe
[ 4856.148781] \x7f
[ 4859.028686] hooked sys_mkdir(), mkdir name: \xd0
                                                   \xad\xac\xfd
[ 4859.028687] \xffffffd0
[ 4859.028688] \xb
[ 4859.028688] \xffffffad
[ 4859.028688] \xffffffac
[ 4859.028688] \xfffffffd
[ 4859.028689] \x7f
[ 4861.413464] hooked sys_mkdir(), mkdir name: \x90|\xb1\xf3\xff
[ 4861.413465] \xffffff90
[ 4861.413465] \x7c
[ 4861.413465] \xffffffb1
[ 4861.413466] \xfffffff3
[ 4861.413466] \xffffffff
```

I'm not clear how to interpret the content of `pathname` param.

Answer (score 1):

Do note you're printing from a __user pointer. In order to actually access this data you must first use something like the `strncpy_from_user` or `copy_from_user` for known-sized structures/buffers.

Comment: I think you are correct but could you please give more intro about the mechanism?  What happened if i directly use such a pointer?What happened if i use strncpy_from_user?

Comment: Accessing a __user pointer directly in kernel is a bad practice and can not only cause errors but rather security issues (time of check/time of use). The data at that address can be swapped out, mapped to a different process or various other issues. You should always first copy the data form the user memory to a kernel buffer and only then access it. You use strncpy_from_user just like a regular strncpy, to a local buffer.

Comment: Now I use `strncpy_from_user(buff,pathname,256);` but I got a returning code -14 (EFAULT), what should I do?

Comment: The SYSCALL returns this code? What do you pass on to the old function pointer? You should use buff in your function and pass on pathname to the old function.

Comment: The old funtion works well by passing the original `pathname` pointer to it, but this pointer seems to be invalid accroding to the result of either `strncpy_from_user()`(return -14) or `strlen_user()`(return 0)

Comment: Just for testing try __get_user() byte-by-byte to see where you fail (or copy_from_user with one byte copy at a time). It fails when the copy fails. Try to see which of the copied bytes failed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183054/discussion-between-knightingale-and-jay).