# Linux x86-64 syscall hooking, path names garbled

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, kernel-module

I've been experimenting with Linux syscall hooking on a x86_64 Linux system, following the standard procedure of patching the `sys_call_table` method table as found in `/proc/kallsyms`.

However in my trampoline, specifically for syscalls that parse a file path such as openat, makedir I seem to be retrieving non human readable file paths as a result of `printk(path)`, where path is the exact formal parameter passed to the syscall that is intercepted.

[image: as seen here]

Could someone explain why I am not able to intercept the human readable path name from a syscall? e.g. `/usr/home/file.txt`.

Problem detour:

```
asmlinkage int sys_access_trampoline(const char __user *path, int mode)
{
    char buffer[STR_MAX];
    strncpy_from_user(buffer, path, strnlen_user(path, PATH_MAX+1));
    printk(buffer);  // prints \xe1\xaa\xff\xff\ etc...
    STUB_ORIGIN();
    return sys_access(path, mode);
}
```

Comment: Most likely there is an error in your copy_from_user call.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, my current implementation:  strncpy_from_user(buffer, path, strnlen_user(path, PATH_MAX+1)) seems to copy the memory correctly, but strings are of the nature: \xab\xe1\xaa\xff\xff\xff\xff...

Comment: Please edit enough of your code in the question to show the problem.

Comment: my apologies, added code for the trampoline

Comment: Note that the 3rd param of `strncpy_from_user` must always be the size of the dest, not the source.

Comment: Maybe check its return code.

Comment: I am receiving  -EFAULT, which seems to be related to user space access. I had assumed that kernel modules always have access to user space memory

Comment: Please add the caller code.  Also, is caller 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: Since the trampoline is running in a hooked context, the caller will be any userspace region that makes use of the access syscall. Thus the caller could potentially be both 32/64 bit. I also managed to find a stackoverflow post very similar to mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53131457/unreadable-content-of-pathname-parameter-in-mkdir-system-call-after-inline but with no conclusive answer.

Comment: Are you sure that you correctly grab the original syscall's arguments? See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59346208/arguments-in-syscall-intercept-using-loadable-kernel-module-seem-to-be-broken) about proper way for grab syscall arguments in newer Linux kernels.

Comment: Thank you Tsyvarev, the information in that post seemed to solve my problem! I'll update my post to include the solution for others.

Comment: Just for future reference, there shouldn't be any *non*-human-readable version of pathnames anywhere - they are just plain ASCII null-terminated strings.  So if you're getting something that doesn't look like the pathname, you're almost certainly just looking at the wrong address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tsyvarev alluded to, the manner in which syscall parameters are passed has changed for newer kernel versions (**> 4.17**) and requires that the intercepting trampoline have the following signature:

```
asmlinkage __type__ sys_foobar(const struct pt_regs * regs).
```

Individual parameters are then accessed via the respective registers, i.e (x86_64)

```
        arg1   arg2   arg3   arg4    arg5   arg6 
regs->  (di)   (si)   (dx)   (r10)   (r8)   (r9)
```

So to get the path string for the access syscall, you would use `regs->di`.

```
asmlinkage int sys_access_trampoline(const struct pt_regs * regs)
{
    char buffer[STR_MAX];
    strncpy_from_user(buffer, regs->di, strnlen_user(path, PATH_MAX+1));
    printk(buffer);  
    STUB_ORIGIN();
    return sys_access(path, mode);
}
```

I now receive the correct ASCII path name.

Thank you to everyone for helping!